# How to make Git pull use rebase by default for all my repositories?

Tags: git

Is there a way to setup the host Git repository such that any `git pull` done from its (local) clones uses `--rebase` by default? By searching on Stack Overflow, I learned about `branch.autosetuprebase`, but it needs to be configured per clone individually.

My project flow is set up such that we `pull` the `develop` branch before `merge`ing a feature branch to it. This `pull` nearly always uses `--rebase`, so I am trying to figure out if this can be the default.

Comment: Why do you want that? I think it's more reasonable to teach the users to actively think about which case will be more appropriate (based on the magnitude of changes they made or expect from upstream)'

Comment: @JonasWielicki Yes, I agree. It is just that some of my team members are new to Git, and I would like to know if there's a way to enforce it to avoid problems during the initial phase (until they have learned it). The team also works remotely in a different timezone, which means they would be stuck for several hours if something goes wrong. Just curious to know if this is possible.

Comment: I think especially for initial setups, it's better to go for merge. Rebase makes much more weird things if your code really diverges. You have to solve the same conflicts over and over again until you push. So if a team member wants to work on some code, always uses rebase and doesn't push until he's done (which newcomers may do, instead of branching themselves), they'll be faced with the same conflicts they have solved X times already.

Comment: @JonasWielicki The team members _do_ make a new branch for each new feature they work on (and this, they have already understood quite well). The need for rebase comes because other developers have committed to the "remote" develop branch by the time he is ready to push his changes. Hence, I would like him to do a pull rebase from remote before pushing his changes. The project itself is quite mature, only the team is new. :) So it is a "initial setup" only in terms of people. What would be your advice for this scenario?

Comment: Replying to your first comment, in a majority of cases (almost all), rebase is the right choice, since it takes a lot of time to thoroughly test a new feature, etc. By the time that is done, there would most certainly be plenty of commits from other developers.

Comment: Hm yeah. In that case it's still important to pull before merging the local working branch in, otherwise you're likely having the (more unpleasant) rebase conflicts :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21027/discussion-between-ap-and-jonas-wielicki)

Comment: I think we should edit the question title to "How to make Git pull use rebase by default in my repository for all consumers?" so, singular repository, since otherwise the question is misleading and it seems you are talking about GitHub or something that hosts all your repositories. Your question is about having your users to rebase as default, and not, doing something on your computer to rebase local repositories as default. Maybe better to clarify since lot of people land here for the second thing, so, having all your repositories (on your computer) with rebase as default.

Answer (score 479, accepted):

There are now 3 different levels of configuration for default pull behaviour. From most general to most fine grained they are:

#### 1. `pull.rebase`

Setting this to `true` means that `git pull` is always equivalent to `git pull --rebase` (unless `branch.<branchname>.rebase` is explicitly set to `false`). This can also be set per repository or globally.

#### 2. `branch.autosetuprebase`

Setting this to `always` means that whenever a tracking branch is created, a configuration entry like the one below will be created for it. For finer grained control, this can also be set to `never`, `local` or `remote` and can be set per repository or globally. See `git config --help` for further details.

#### 3. `branch.<branchname>.rebase`

Setting this to `true` means that that particular branch will always pull from its upstream via rebasing, unless `git pull --no-rebase` is used explicitly.

## Conclusion

So while you can't change the default behaviour for all future clones of a repository, you can change the default for all of the current user's (existing and future) repositories via `git config --global pull.rebase true`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was exploring if I could have a setting so that anyone who clones the repository has it enabled by default. The above setting would be stored in `~/.gitconfig`, which means each developer who clones the host repository would need to run the command. Not complaining about your solution. It is a good one, I just want to confirm I understood your point correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does indeed look like this is as close as one can get.

Answer (score 350):

How about

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
```

This will tell git to always pull with rebase.

Comment: Thanks, this works great for existing tracking branches.

Comment: this doesn't work for me: git config --global pull.rebase false

Comment: Great tip, now I can't pull anymore: `fatal: Cannot rebase onto multiple branches.`

Comment: @leonheess `git pull --merge`. You're just changing the default; the merge option is still available.

Comment: @flyx but I want to rebase pull?

Comment: @leonheess Well in your scenario it simply isn't possible. I assumed you want a solution for cases where rebase isn't possible. If you want an analysis of your scenario, you'll need to ask a new question.

Answer (score 82):

## The answer is no.

There isn't a way to set up a remote repository so that everyone who clones it has the default behaviour of `git pull` changed.

You can, however, set up a server-side hook that checks that no one pushes merge commits ([something like this](http://devblog.nestoria.com/post/98892582763/maintaining-a-consistent-linear-history-for-git-log), perhaps).

There are also some configuration options that you may be interested in. All the developers who clone from the remote repository will have to set it themselves manually.

### 1. Option `branch.<name>.rebase`

You can configure a local branch to always use `--rebase`, like this, replacing `<name>` with a branch name:

```
git config branch.<name>.rebase true
```

After running this on `master`, the `master` section in `.git/config` looked like this:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
    rebase = true
```

### 2. Option `branch.autosetuprebase`

Running that previous config command for every Git branch can be a hassle, so you can configure Git to automatically set it up for every new branch:

```
git config branch.autosetuprebase always
```

(You can also specify `never`, `remote`, and `local`, see `man git-config` for details.)

Without the `--global` option, the configuration is saved to `.git/config`, and only the current repository is affected. With `--global`, the configuration is saved to `~/.gitconfig`, and every unconfigured repository is affected.

This option does not affect already existing branches.

### 3. Option `pull.rebase`

```
git config pull.rebase true
```

(You can also give it the `--global` option.)

If this option is true, running `git pull` is equivalent to `git pull --rebase`, unless `branch.<name>.rebase` has been set to `false`.

Comment: The only answer that actually answers the question.

Comment: Tip: enable the `autoStash` option for Git so that you can run "git pull --rebase" even with a dirty working tree: https://cscheng.info/2017/01/26/git-tip-autostash-with-git-pull-rebase.html

Answer (score 8):

Currently there is no way to set the default policy for a repository.

If you want it for yourself and you use at least git 1.7.9, you can globally set the `pull.rebase` configuration as follow:

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
```

But you'll have to do on each machine. One option could be to configure the default user home template/skeleton with that option. Users might, however, change that option.

If you don't want merges, you could define a server-side hook to reject pushes with merges.

For your reference, his is the [source documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-pullrebase) for pull.rebase:

> When true, rebase branches on top of the fetched branch, instead of merging the default branch from the default remote when "git pull"
>   is run. See "branch..rebase" for setting this on a per-branch
>   basis.
>
> When merges, pass the --rebase-merges option to git rebase so that the local merge commits are included in the rebase (see [git-rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)
>   for details).
>
> When preserve, also pass --preserve-merges along to git rebase so that locally committed merge commits will not be flattened by running
>   git pull.
>
> When the value is interactive, the rebase is run in interactive mode.
>
> NOTE: this is a possibly dangerous operation; do not use it unless you understand the implications (see [git-rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) for details).

Answer (score 4):

This makes the `--rebase` option the default when issuing a `git pull`  on a given branch.

@Flimm, I needed to add `true` to make your first option work.

So the correct syntax is:

```
git config branch.<branch>.rebase true
```

To run this command on the `develop` branch:

```
git config branch.develop.rebase true
```

And now the `develop` section in `.git/config` looks like this:

```
[branch "develop"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/develop
        rebase = true
```

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my answer, in the future, feel free to edit the answer yourself.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `.gitconfig` and want to use `merge` instead of `rebase` when pulling, you can insert this snippet into your `.gitconfig`:

```
[pull]
  rebase = false
```

This will remove the annoying warning on each new project you set up.

Comment: OP is precisely asking for the opposite of what you're describing.