# Git making merge commits when pulling

Tags: git

When moving to version `1.8.3.2` of git I'm encountering an unexpected issue. Every time I pull it makes a new merge commit. Previously when I did a pull I think it did a rebase, but at any rate it didn't make a commit for just the pull. How do I get this behavior back? My configuration hasn't changed. Not sure if it's relevant, but I have `branch.autosetuprebase=always`.

Comment: What if you do an explicit `git pull --rebase`? Also isn't there a branch-specific config value `branch.<branchname>.rebase=false`?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to make Git pull use rebase by default for all clones?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846300/how-to-make-git-pull-use-rebase-by-default-for-all-clones)

Comment: They do look pretty similar, but my problem wasn't quite the same as his.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. The repo was copied over to a new installation with its existing git configuration, and the branches were set up without `rebase = true`, but the old machine had `git config --global pull.rebase true`, so it didn't make merge commits. Either adding `rebase = true` to all of the existing branches should do the trick, or what we did was setting pulls to rebase as well.

Answer (score -1):

Either create [a `.gitconfig` alias entry for `git pull`](https://github.com/Droogans/dotfiles/blob/d0e63a890abdf66e4e7475631f2ae97c94c511e6/.gitconfig#L35), or set it to always do this for you automatically: http://stevenharman.net/git-pull-with-automatic-rebase.

Comment: Like I mentioned, I already have `autosetuprebase always` set in my gitconfig, like is recommended in the article.