# How to prevent git branching and merge on same branch?

Tags: git, merge, pull

I had to do some work on my laptop on the `dev` branch, which I then pushed.

Later, I did some work on the desktop, also on `dev`, and when I went to push it, it failed with a message "fetch first".  I did a pull and merged, then pushed.

It ended up looking like this:

[image]

As you can see, I get a split in the `dev` branch with a merge.  Obviously, this would have been prevented if I had remembered to fetch first before my commit.

But at the point where bitbucket rejected the push, is there anything I could have done to prevent the merge and get a nice straight timeline?

Comment: `git pull --rebase` would be what you're looking for (instead of `fetch`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When do you use git rebase instead of git merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/when-do-you-use-git-rebase-instead-of-git-merge)

Comment: See also [this answer in particular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/804178/1267663) which describes the difference between merging (what you did) and rebasing (what you describe as your desired "nice straight timeline")

Comment: Related: [How to make Git pull use rebase by default for all my repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13846300/1542723)