# I did a git push --force and now my git is crazy

Tags: git, gitlab

I was being unable to push my commits into origin, then I did a "git push origin develop -f". The problem is my head is 3 commits ahead origin and I can't push it because it is saying Everything up to date. How do I deal with it without losing my changes?

[image]

Comment: You have uncommited changes, so those will not be pushed. Run `git status` to see if things are staged that you want, then `git commit` when things are ready.

Comment: I don't see `-f` in the push on that screenshot, but I do see a fatal error reported by `pull` which says that a `cherry-pick` operation is in-progress. Have you solved that already?

Comment: I used the force before the print, here is my git status with nothing to commit: https://pastebin.com/jUksmauR

Comment: `git status` tells us: `You are currently rebasing branch 'develop' on '119d09a'.`
So you have to finish your rebase or abort it and then you should have a clean state again. (Did you have a setting which [defaults to rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13974638) when pulling?)

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle difference between the two commands :

- `git pull origin develop` will fetch the remote `develop` branch from `origin` and merge it into **your active local branch** ,
- `git push origin develop` will take **your local `develop` branch** (*not* your current branch), and push it to its remote counterpart.

In your situation, as `git log` correctly shows : `develop` and `origin/develop` are already on the same commit, hence the `Everything up-to-date` message on your `git push` (even with the `-f` flag),
and apparently, you still have an unresolved `cherry-pick` pending, so git will not start the `merge` part of your `git pull` command.

---

It also looks like you are in the middle of something else :

- git mentions an undergoing `cherry-pick` (did you by any chance fix conflicts on a `git cherry-pick` command you ran ?),
- your `git log` shows that you are currently in a detached HEAD state

so you probably need to sort this out before proceeding.

Run `git status`, it should give you some insights on what's going on, and if you are indeed in the middle of a cherry-pick.

---

[edit] it turns out the action in progress is a rebase. Complete the rebase first.