# Improving a git rebase workflow

Tags: git

I'm currently working a very simple git workflow using feature branches and rebasing on to master before pushing.

```
git checkout -b feature
.. make some commits
git checkout master
git pull
```

If there are no changes from the pull:

```
git merge feature
git push
```

If there are changes:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge feature
git push
```

While has been great to learn how git works but it's getting a little tedious to type all the time and I suspect there's some faster ways to achieve what I'm doing but can't find them.

Comment: You should check the examples from the [git-rebase man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html), instead of a checkout followed by rebase you could simply do `git rebase master feature`. But see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20420258/321973) for an even simpler way...

Comment: By the way, do you know ["A successful Git branching model"](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)? Totally worth a read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your shortest amount of steps had a total of 6 steps (no changes case):

```
git checkout -b feature
.. make some commits
git checkout master
git pull
git merge feature
git push
```

This technique should work in both cases (6 steps as well):

```
git checkout -b feature
.. make some commits
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
git checkout master
git merge feature
```

Comment: For the last rebase step I'd suggest using `git merge --no-ff` so work can easily be identified. This avoids fast forward.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could use [`git pull --rebase`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html) *after* merging, which does just that:

> -r
>   --rebase
>
> Rebase the current branch on top of the upstream branch after fetching. If there is a remote-tracking branch corresponding to the
>   upstream branch and the upstream branch was rebased since last
>   fetched, the rebase uses that information to avoid rebasing non-local
>   changes.
>
> See `pull.rebase, branch.<name>.rebase` and `branch.autosetuprebase` in [`git-config`(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) if you want to make git pull always use --rebase
>   instead of merging.
>
> ## Note
>
> This is a potentially dangerous mode of operation. It rewrites history, which does not bode well when you published that history
>   already. Do not use this option unless you have read [`git-rebase`(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html)
>   carefully.

So in summary:

```
git branch -b feature
...
git checkout master
git merge feature  # By the way, merge's --no-ff might interest you
git pull --rebase  # rebases feature onto the new-fetched head if necessary
```

---

Just one note: The result of this is *slightly* different from your way if you made changes to `master` as well, since `git pull --rebase` rebases *all* your changes since the last `pull/push` onto the pulled `HEAD`, while you way would cause the pulled changes and your `master` changes to be merged and then `feature` be rebased upon that. This is mostly irrelevant (and personally I prefer not having unnecessary `pull`-induced merges in my history) but you should be aware of it nonetheless...

In pictures, before:

```
 /-O          origin/master
C--A--B       master
    \--F--G   feature
```

After your way:

```
 /-O-----\  
C--A--B--C*-----(FG)  (origin/)master - fast-forward merge (unless --no-ff)
          \-F-G-/     feature (rebased!)
```

`git pull --rebase` way:

```
 /-O
C--A--B--M*  => C--O--A--B--M*  (origin/)master
   \-F-G-/                      feature (not rebased!)
```

If instead you want the end result to be

```
C--O--A--B--F--G
```

use

```
git branch -b feature
...
git checkout master
git rebase feature
git pull --rebase
```

Also note how much fun you can have with `git-rebase -i` ;)

Comment: For a nice discussion of `git-pull --rebase` have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/4675513/321973

Answer (score 2):

probably a nice alias could improve your workflow a little bit, I use this one

```
# full rebase
frb = "!sh -c 'x=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` && echo "rebasing to $0 ..." && git rebase $0 && git checkout $0 && git rebase $x'"
```

usage (on feature branch):

```
git frb master
```

of course you could also add a checkout at the beginning and push at the end

... tested on git 1.9.3 (osx), not tested what happens if there are conflicts