# GIt: Sync vs. Git: Sync (Rebase) in Visual Studio Code (VSC)

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

When using Visual Studio Code, there are multiple ways to push and pull, but the one I used to use, `Git: Sync`, rarely works as expected anymore. I always have better results with `Git: Sync (Rebase)`. The problem is I cannot find the difference between the two. I have looked at various documentation areas, such as this link: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28

There does not appear to be any help documentation that describes the specific differences between the two commands.

Running `Git: Sync` produces the following dialog:
[image]

However, running `Git: Sync (Rebase)` also produces the following dialog:
[image]

As you can see, both dialogs are precisely the same. I am not a git expert by any stretch of the imagination, and I think I generally understand how `rebase` works, but I am struggling with the difference between the two commands.

My apologies up-front if there is clear documentation for these two commands, but I cannot find it.

Could you please explain the differences between `Git: Sync` and the `Git: Sync (Rebase)` features in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Do you have reason to think that it is anything other than `git push` preceded by `git pull` vs `git pull --rebase`? In other words, when we pull, one's a merge (which might be a fast-forward, or not) and one's a rebase.

Comment: If you're not familiar with `git pull --rebase`, read up on it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472254/when-should-i-use-git-pull-rebase and https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull